# How can I calculate BezierFunction points by hand?

Tags: plotting, approximation

For example, I know that the control points are `{0, 0}`, `{1, 0}` and `{2, 3}` and I need to calculate the point in 0.5, so

```
BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 3}}][0.5] = ?
```

Comment: `BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 3}}][0.5]` gives `{1., 0.75}`, so what is your problem?

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to know how the calculation is worked out (by hand).